# Javascript AlgoliaJS .clearCache() on empty search results is always a "search behind"

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have a function that is executed each time a user updates an entry, in order to keep the list of entries up-to-date. The problem I'm running into is that when I run .clearCache() on the index, even though I'm doing it before the actual search function is run, it takes two reloads in order to get the latest updates. It's acting as if it's a reload behind. I have no idea what's causing this, but here is my search function:

```
search() {

   this.results = [];
    // Clear the algolia cache
    this.auditionsIndex.clearCache();
    this.auditionsIndex.search('', options).then(result => {
      if(result.hits && result.hits.length > 0) {
         this.results = result.hits;
      } 

      // Clear the cache one more time
      this.auditionsIndex.clearCache();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing something in an Algolia index happens asynchronously, when you execute something like `index.saveObject()` the result of the Promise/callback will be an object with `taskId`. You can then `index.waitTask` for that task, and send some event to your frontend to let it know to clear the cache and search.

see https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/wait-task/#methods

Comment: Hmm is there any way I could use this on the front-end? I have a node server that basically listens to Firebase tree nodes for any changes and once it has done that, it automatically adds/updates/removes objects from Algolia. Since it's all in real-time, there's no real way to "Wait" and then send that to the front-end :/